# Identity Pool Role Can't Access S3 Bucket Access Point

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

**Summary:** I am using AWS Amplify Auth class with a pre-configured Cognito User Pool for authentication. After authentication, I am using the Cognito ID token to fetch identity pool credentials (using AWS CredentialProviders SDK) whose assumed role is given access to an S3 access point. I then attempt to fetch a known object from the bucket's access point using the AWS S3 SDK. The problem is that the request returns a response of `403 Forbidden` instead of successfully getting the object, despite my role policy and bucket (access point) policy allowing the `s3:GetObject` action on the resource.

I am assuming something is wrong with the way my policies are set up. Code snippets below.

I am also concerned I'm not getting the right role back from the credentials provider, but I don't allow unauthenticated roles on the identity pool so I am not sure, and I don't know how to verify the role being sent back in the credentials' session token to check.

I also may not be configuring the sdk client objects properly, but I followed the documentation provided to the best of my understanding from the documentation (I am using AWS SDK v3, not v2, so slightly different syntax and uses modular imports)

**Backend Configurations - IAM**

Identity Pool: Authenticated Role Trust Policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Federated": "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
                "sts:TagSession"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud": "<MY_IDENTITY_POOL_ID>"
                },
                "ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
                    "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr": "authenticated"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Identity Pool: Authenticated Role S3 Access Policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<MY_ACCESS_POINT_NAME>/object/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Backend Configurations - S3**

S3 Bucket and Access Points: Block All Public Access

S3 Bucket CORS Policy:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "HEAD"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 300
    }
]
```

S3 Bucket Policy (Delegates Access Control to Access Points):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "DelegateAccessControlToAccessPoints",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<MY_BUCKET_NAME>",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<MY_BUCKET_NAME>/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:DataAccessPointAccount": "<MY_ACCT_ID>"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Access Point Policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowAccessPointToGetObjects",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<ACCT_ID>:role/<MY_IDENTITY_POOL_AUTH_ROLE_NAME>"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:<REGION>:<ACCT_ID>:accesspoint/<MY_ACCESS_POINT_NAME>/object/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Front End AuthN & AuthZ**

Amplify Configuration of User Pool Auth

```js
Amplify.configure({
  Auth: {
    region: '<REGION>',
    userPoolId: '<MY_USER_POOL_ID>',
    userPoolWebClientId: '<MY_USER_POOL_APP_CLIENT_ID>'
  }
})
```

User AuthZ process:
On user login event, call Amplify's `Auth.signIn()` which returns type `CognitoUser`:

```js
// Log in user (error checking ommitted here for post)
const CognitoUser = await Auth.signIn(email, secret);

// Get ID Token JWT
const CognitoIdToken = CognitoUser.signInUserSession.getIdToken().getJwtToken();

// Use @aws-sdk/credentials-provider to get Identity Pool Credentials
const credentials = fromCognitoIdentityPool({
    clientConfig: { region: '<REGION>' },
    identityPoolId: '<MY_IDENTITY_POOL_ID>',
    logins: {
        'cognito-idp.<REGION>.amazonaws.com/<MY_USER_POOL_ID>': CognitoIdToken
    }
})

// Create S3 SDK Client
client = new S3Client({
    region: '<REGION>',
    credentials
})

// Format S3 GetObjectCommand parameters for object to get from access point
const s3params = {
    Bucket: '<MY_ACCESS_POINT_ARN>',
    Key: '<MY_OBJECT_KEY>'
}

// Create S3 client command object
const getObjectCommand = new GetObjectCommand(s3params);

// Get object from access point (execute command)
const response = await client.send(getObjectCommand); // -> 403 FORBIDDEN
```